# Como printar duas listas em um relatório jasper?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports, jasper

Tenho duas listas com objetos distintos e que podem crescer muito, como eu faço para colocar as duas listas em forma de tabela em um relatorio? consigo fazer isso no band de detail, mas quando a tabela cresce muito, eu recebo um erro de overflow : "Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow"

Comment: Você poderia compartilhar o jrxml, por favor?

Comment: Olá, você precisa adicionar um exemplo minimo viavel do problema e algum comentário sobre o que você fez, precisa de algum exemplo escrito.